# How insert into database both value and content?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

How insert both value and content into database separate separate column. Its a dropdown menu. Like

```
<select name="name" id="name">
<option value="000">Please select</option>
<option value="calendar.gif">Animal Welfare</option>
<option value="calendar1.gif">Art and Cultural</option>
<option value="calendar2.gif">Career Related</option>
</select>
```

For the instance "Animal welfare", want to insert "calendar.gif" to one column and "Animal welfare" to another column.

Comment: The server sent the list of values and human friendly names to the client in the first place. You should be able to associate them without having the client send both back to you.

Answer (score 2):

Store the option => value combinations in an array. You can then use this array for both inserting and displaying, eg

```
$options = array (
    'calendar.gif'  => 'Animal Welfare',
    'calendar1.gif' => 'Art and Cultural',
    'calendar2.gif' => 'Career Related'
);

if (isset($_POST['name']) && array_key_exists($_POST['name'], $options)) {
    // valid option submitted

    $key = $_POST['name'];
    $value = $options[$key];

    // now you can insert $key and $value
}

// to display
?>

<select name="name" id="name">
<option value="">Please select</option>
<?php foreach ($options as $key => $value) : ?>
<option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($key) ?>">
    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($value) ?>
</option>
<?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

Comment: @Phil Thank you so much....but the content like "animal welfare" not inserting into database....

Comment: @Kingfisher Show some code, I can't debug air (edit your question to add more information)

Answer (score 1):

Only the string in the `value` attribute is sent to the server.

If you wanted the text node as well, you'd need to use JavaScript (possibly XHR).

An example using JavaScript might be...

```
var selectedOptionTextNode = document.createElement('input');

selectedOptionTextNode.type = 'hidden';

selectedOptionTextNode.name = 'selected-text-node';

document.body.appendChild(selectedOptionTextNode);

document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].addEventListener('change', function() {
     selectedOptionTextNode.value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
}, false);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/RM3mc/).

Now the text node will also be submitted to the server.

**However**, by far the best way to do this is per [Phil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006687/how-insert-into-database-both-value-and-content/7006741#7006741), i.e. associate the keys with values on your server.

Comment: Hey! How do you know my last name? Stalker! BTW, +1 for not immediately resorting to jQuery ;)

Comment: @Phil Oh whoops, I completely forgot you dropped the *Brown*!